# How to get an ID of a selected item in a combobox. C# Metro App

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have a combo box where which gets values from an API. I want to get the ID of the selected item in that combobox because the data in my next view changes based on the value selected here.

My Combobox.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSubjects" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE5DBE8" Width="141" SelectedItem="Maths" Margin="0,217,957,247" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsSubjects}}" PlaceholderText="Select"/>
```

This is how I populate it.

```
private async void getSubjects()
         {
             try
             {
                 string subjects = baseAddress + "subjects";
                 var cont = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(subjects));
                 subjectHelper data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<subjectHelper>(cont);

                 foreach (var item in data.result)
                 {
                     cmbSubjects.Items.Add(item.name);
                 }

             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
                 messageDialog.ShowAsync();
             }

         }
```

My Classes:

```
public class Subject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public curriculum curriculam { get; set; }
    }

    class subjectHelper
    {
        public List<Subject> result { get; set; }
    }

    public class unit
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public int teachingHours { get; set; }
        public int isMandotory { get; set; }
        public Subject subject { get; set; }
    }

    class unitHelper
    {
        public List<unit> result { get; set; }
    }
```

The user will be able to select the Subject in the combo box so I want it to return the Subject so I can load the units dynamically according to the subject.

Someone please help me do this..
Any kind of help is appreciated......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code a little for this.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSubjects" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE5DBE8" Width="141" SelectedItem="Maths" Margin="0,217,957,247" PlaceholderText="Select">            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

and set itemssource as follows:

```
cmbSubjects.ItemsSource=data.Result;
```

and then in SelectionChanged event

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Subject selectedSubject = cmbSubjects.SelectedItem as Subject;
if(selectedSubject!=null){
  int selectedSubID = selectedSubject.ID;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Combobox has a `SelectionChanged` event, you can catch your selected item from your combobox whenever you select a new item, in that event trigger you can catch the object and pass the ID.

After modification your combobox will be like below after adding `SelectionChanged` property in XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbSubjects" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE5DBE8" Width="141" SelectedItem="Maths" Margin="0,217,957,247" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsSubjects}}"  PlaceholderText="Select" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

your code behind will be

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Subject selectedSubject = cmbSubjects.SelectedItem as Subject;
  int selectedSubID = selectedSubject.ID;
}
```

Comment: I edited my code right after my post, I've added wrong property correct one will be SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" , is it possible to check this?

Comment: Btw I assumed that when you're binding Items source, I thought it's list of Subject  from here. ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsSubjects}}", you're just binding name as text on code behind, this method will only work if you bind List of 'Subject' object. You can bind them as list and it'll work other wise if names are unique you need have a method to check for their IDs seperately.

Comment: cmbSubjects.Items.Add(item.name); This is how I add the item. 

cvsSubjects.source = data.result; populates my combobox with the path to that class